# Remove specific characters at beginning and end of string

Tags: php, replace

I am using PHP and I am trying to remove all underscore characters from the end and beginning of a string.

Here's the string: `____a_b_c__________`
And I want the result to be: `a_b_c`

I have tried with this regular expression but it's not working:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z]+\Z/i', '', '____a_b_c__________');
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$string = trim($string, '_');
```

Regex is for pattern matching `___` is not a pattern it's just underlines.

But if I was gonna use a Regex, I'd do something like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^_+|_+$/', '', $string);
```

For the regular expression

- `^` is the start of a line
- `_` is underline, the `+` is one or more
- `|` is OR
- `_` is underline, the `+` is one or more
- `$` is the end of line

Then we just replace it with `''`

Comment: Ha! I cant believe it was that easy. Thanks.

Comment: everything is easy for me, well almost everything.

Comment: How about this one: how would I remove all duplicate and triplicate ___ underscores from a string. Sometime there may even be 5 - 10 underscores, i just want it to be one underscore.

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/_{2,}/', '_', $string);` or `'/_+/'` or `$string = preg_replace(['/^_+|_+$/','/_{2,}/'],['', '_'], $string);`