# ACCESS VBA - Export File has " at end and beginning of a row

Tags: vba, ms-access

Explanation: My code imports a textfile and changes at a specific col spaces into the number 19. I succeded to do this by using left and right in vba.

I dont know why but my written Code is adding " at the end and beginning of my exported loops. I already searched for a solution and found this question [Remove specific characters at beginning and end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724039/remove-specific-characters-at-beginning-and-end-of-string)

Is there something wrong with my code? i am confused at this point.

My Code:

```
Sub Text()
'open File and save as string

Dim strFilter As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileNameSecond As String

strFileNameSecond = "new.txt"


  strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Text Files (*.TXT)", "*.TXT")
  strFileName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=True, _
                DialogTitle:="Please select an input file...", _
                Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

'load selected file and save as new file

Dim strZeile
Dim strRepMid As String

Open strFileName For Input As #1
Open strFileNameSecond For Output As #2

Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strZeile

    strRepMid = Left(strZeile, 40) & "19" & Right(strZeile, 68)

    Write #2, strRepMid
Loop

Close #1    'close file
Close #2
End Sub
```

My Textfile:

```
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       0000000000     jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr
```

File after export:

```
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
"kjhcae48ovawpovmslövsae       000000000019   jhkfkgnskhvfnslkfvmkjrdacösle<nvsel,fösfvjmykljc,gkvyndngmbrhjgsr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Write #`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement) will process data in order to read it with `Input #` into structured variables.

This includes wrapping strings with double quotes.

If you don't want any processing/formatting, use [`Print #`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement) instead of `Write #`.

i.e.

```
Print #2, strRepMid
```

Comment: thank you i solved my problem and marked your answer as helpful